# How to include a lot images?

Tags: graphics, best-practices

I recently faced with the need to include a lot big images.

Here was some problem: I must write new `figure` enviroment for every image, otherwise  if I use one enviroment for a few images, they behave unpredictably.

For example, in case, when image must be on next page because place is over instead of it, two images compile on next page, leaving a empty space on the previous page.

Is there a way to include a lot images without writing tons of enviroments?
 Code with one enviroment

```
\documentclass[floatsection,equationsection,14pt,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\No}{\ifmmode{\nfss@text{\textnumero}}\else\textnumero\fi}
    \begin{document}
        \section{Report}
        \par dfsvsbsertgbsefgbsaefbsefvbeasrvaevesafrvawervaewrvaewrvaewrvawer.
        \section{Work progress}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{untitled.png}
    \caption{plot $W(s)=\frac{K}{s}$ }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{impulse-w2.eps}
    \caption{plot $W(s)=\frac{K}{s}$ }
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

which produces [image]

Same code, but every image have own enviroment.

```
\documentclass[floatsection,equationsection,14pt,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtext} 
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\No}{\ifmmode{\nfss@text{\textnumero}}\else\textnumero\fi}
    \begin{document}
        \section{Report}
        \par dfsvsbsertgbsefgbsaefbsefvbeasrvaevesafrvawervaewrvaewrvaewrvawer.
        \section{Work progress}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{untitled.png}
    \caption{plot $W(s)=\frac{K}{s}$ }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{impulse-w2.eps}
    \caption{plot $W(s)=\frac{K}{s}$ }
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Which produces[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem. `figure` is a floating environment, if there is not enough space in this page, it will move to next possible place. If all contents are `figures`, of course there will be empty spaces. If you have paragraphs, the text will flow trying to fill spaces.

Comment: you do not need to use `figure` at all, you can just have 1000 `\includegraphics` with a blank line between each and you will get 1000 images in the document. It is not clear what you did, or what error you got.

Comment: I added some examples to explain this case. I hope this  make  my thoughts clearer. By the way, can '\caption'  work without float?

Comment: You have to use `\captionof{figure}{my nice little caption} \label{mylabel}`. This command is defined in the `cap-of` package, or in `caption` (it's better to load the latter, as it also has many possibilities to format captions layout).

Comment: It's not possible to break a `figure` environment between pages. A `figure` can contain several `subfigures` (if they fit in a page), and if you need to distribute `subfigures` between several pages, you should use different `figure` environment with `continuation captions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `[h]` makes it *much* harder for latex to place the figures: the main effect of that is to not allow `p` so you are preventing latex making a page that only has figures and forcing it to make pages with text and figures but giving it no text, so it can not achieve the constraints you have set.

But here you should not use `figure` at all just use `\includegraphics` and if you want captions, use `\captionof{figure}{...}` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages.